Select only columns from a table that are listed in a column of another table, PowerBI
Table2 has only one column with values Name, Zip and Phone. Table1 has 50 columns including Name, Zip and Phone. How can I only select the columns in Table1 which are part of the values of the only column of Table2. The idea is to add more values to Table2 in the future, so those columns will be selected automatically in Table1.
Example:
Table2 (only one column)



cols




Name


Zip


Phone



Table1 (50 columns in total, not all columns shown)



Name
Zip
Phone
Latitude
Longitude




Name1
Zip1
Phone1
Latitude1
Longitude1


Name2
Zip2
Phone2
Latitude2
Longitude2



Result table needed:



Name
Zip
Phone




Name1
Zip1
Phone1


Name2
Zip2
Phone2



If a new value is added in Table2, for example, I add 'Latitude', Table2 will look like this:



cols




Name


Zip


Phone


Latitude



and the Result table needed will look like this:



Name
Zip
Phone
Latitude




Name1
Zip1
Phone1
Latitude1


Name2
Zip2
Phone2
Latitude2




could you pls provide some sample data and expected output?

I might know the answer to this but need to see some sample data and know if the records are unique in each table of is the same record can appear multiple times.

Please check the example provided. I'm using Power BI Desktop to accomplish this work. The tables come from Dataverse. I'm trying to use Table.SelectColumns function inside the query, with no success so far.
